# Angular and .Net Core Project VS 2022: An unhandled exception occurred: Project 'Leon\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https\<projectName>.pem' does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Hello I am building an Angular/.Net Core project and creating the projects by following Microsoft's suggestion, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022. I created one on my laptop which starts without a problem and one on my PC which fails. The key difference and what I suspect to be the problem is that my username on my PC has a space,"Eric Leon", while on my laptop is "eric.leon" but I can't figure out how to fix it. I searched articles and made sure that everything looked good on the angular.json and package.json files.
This is the Error
[image]

The error log does not contain more relevant information than the output. **Notice how the Project starts with `Leon\AppData\...` instead of `C:\users\Eric Leon\...`** and this is why I suspect the username is the problem, because it looks like its cutting of the path at the space in the username. I also looked at the aspnetcore-https.js which seems to be building the path and even replaced the `baseFolder` with a hardcoded path with that contained %20 in the name `const baseFolder = 'C:/Users/Eric%20Leon/AppData/Roaming/ASP.NET\https'`.
[image]
After hours of looking at this I haven't had success so far so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **package.json** the start path for the **.pem** file and the **.key** file is specified.
`"ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https..."`
**--ssl-cert** should contain **C:\Users** and **%APPDATA%** should contain **username\APPDATA\Roaming** but in this case --ssl-cert included the first part of my username (firstname) and %APPDATA% started from the second part of the username (lastname). The solution was to put double quotes around %APPDATA% since command line tools only support double quotes and escape them with backslash since its in a json file.
so `"ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert \"%APPDATA%\"\\ASP.NET\\https..."`

Prior to that I was working around the issue by putting the files in a folder on the C drive and hardcoding the path.